# How to use an executor for each stage inside a declarative parallel step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to adapt some old multi-job in a declarative Pipeline.
I would like that every stage on parallel step in a Declarative Pipeline use its own executor.

The behaviour that I'm getting is that Jenkins is using the same executor to run all the stages.

```
pipeline {

agent { label 'macmini'}
    stages() { 
        stage('SCM') {
            steps{
                //clone repo
            }
        }
        stage('Heavy build Stage'){

            parallel {

            stage ("First Job"){ 
                steps {  
                    //do some heavy work
                    sleep 100
                }
              }
              stage ("Second Job"){
                  steps {
                  //do some heavy work
                        sleep 100
                      }
                  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, I want that stage ("First Job") and ("Second Job") use it's own executor. But Jenkins is using only one executor to run both stages... it's also important that they use the same workspace.

If I set an agent/node after each stage, they will run in its own  executor but it will also create a new Workspace (my-job@2).

---

### Edit

Just to make myself clear, I'm used to work with executor to balance the work of a job between my different slaves. I know (empirically) that each slave can run 4 stages in parallel. Those jobs are trigger by a webhook.

So if a job starts I will get

```
slave 1
1. idle
2. idle
3. (Heavy Build Stage) #1
4. idle
```

If three more jobs are trigged I will get the following scenario

```
slave 1
1. (Heavy Build Stage) #2
2. (Heavy Build Stage) #3
3. (Heavy Build Stage) #1
4. (Heavy Build Stage) #4
```

Which means that I'm with 8 stages running (2 stages in parallel * 4 builds)

What I'm looking for is a way to split every stage to use it's own executor, so I can get the following scenario

```
Build Queue
1. job #3
2. job #4

slave 1
1. (Heavy Build Stage / Second Jo) #2
2. (Heavy Build Stage / First job) #2
3. (Heavy Build Stage / Second Job) #1
4. (Heavy Build Stage / First job) #1
```

When I try the solution of setting an agent/node after each stage

```
stage("First Job"){
agent{ label SLAVE_NAME }
...
}
```

It works but each stage runs in it's own workspace (creates a new folder with a @2), but I would like them to run in the same workspace.

I have the same behaviour when using customWorkspace option for each stage

```
agent {
  node {
  label "macmini"
  customWorkspace 'teste'
 }
}
```

The logs shows

```
Running in /Users/mobile/jenkins/teste
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] ws
Running in /Users/mobile/jenkins/teste@2
```

Comment: the idea of agents are blocking you to have same workspace, that's obvious if they are on different machines right ? it is not yet obvious when they are on same machine, but then it is different folders, so actually you have to make sure to use agents which are installed on same machine as well as use `dir` to ensure they gonna pickup/reuse same directory for doing work inside

Comment: I will add more information to make myself clear, but I believe that the behaviour that I'm expecting is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

First you need 2 agents. Every agent get its own label ('jenkinsagent1' and 'jenkinsagent2' in the example below). The global pipeline is not given an agent. Every stage gets its own agent.

```
pipeline{

    agent none //this tells the pipeline that it is not executed by 1 agent

        stage('Is parallel executed on 2 agents') {
             parallel {

                 stage('foo'){
                       agent{
                          node { label'jenkinsagent1' //executed by this agent
                           customWorkspace 'myWorkspace/test' //use this workspace
                          } 
                       }
                       steps { // do something}
                  }

                  stage('bar'){
                       agent{
                          node { label 'jenkinsagent1' //execute on this agent
                        customWorkspace 'myWorkspace/test'} } //use this workspace
                       steps { // do something different} //executed by the other agent
                  } //closing stage bar
    } //closing parallel
// closing pipeline
```

Be careful if you want to add a 3rd or 4th stage. You always have to set the agent for every new stage. If you don't do it the pipeline won't work.

Comment: I belive I didn't make myself clear enough. They need to execute on the same agent and workspace. I believe that the behaviour I'm expecting is not supported (every stage using it's own executor) but running on same workspace.

Comment: It is possible to let multiple stages be executed by 1 agent. Futhermore it is possible to do this in the same workspace but I guess this may cause some trouble because of locked files etc. Edit: I supplemented my answer. Both stages are executed in the same workspace and on the same agent.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I tried customWorkspace before, and does not work. Jenkins will try to create a @2 folder. I get the following: Running in /Users/mobile/jenkins/teste and Running in /Users/mobile/jenkins/teste@2

Comment: customWorkspace WILL generate additional workspace dirs to avoid a collision, however, if you know the workspace dir you NEED to be running the stages commands in, you can save it as a var and change to the location in every stage.